# (Python: discord.py) ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, discord.py

trying to download discord.py using pip install, gave me the error message in the title.
I installed using cmd and the commands py -m pip install -U discord, the cmd was also run in admin.
tried using pip, pip3, and pip3.9, all of which didnt work.

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling/upgrading (in that order) the said libraries:

- pip
- yarl
- multidict
- wheel
- setuptools

versions of python that I tried (in all versions are downloaded with default settings with nothing changed):
python-3.9.0-amd64.exe
python-3.9.0.exe

I tried researching about wheels and tried installing with --no-binary :all: as well, but it gave the same error message below.

in all the iterations of what I have tried, it churned out the exact same error message without any deviation

ples help :<

````
  Using cached discord-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting discord.py>=1.0.1
  Using cached discord.py-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (701 kB)
Processing c:\users\mt\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\9c\bd\6b99bc6ec9dab11f3756d31fb8506d3ecf07aea58b6201f539\aiohttp-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting chardet<4.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.5.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl, multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mt\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\mt\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\MT\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptlhkh7zi'
       cwd: C:\Users\MT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nztu4nu2\yarl
  Complete output (35 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mt\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\mt\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\MT\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzb98brnr'
       cwd: C:\Users\MT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nztu4nu2\multidict
  Complete output (40 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build yarl multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, multidict which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly```
````

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message?
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Discord.py v1.6 has been released earlier today, fixing this issue

Comment: install GCC  << apt install -y build-essential >> for debian linux base images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also had the exact same issue today, since i downloaded node.js and it updated my python 8 to python 9 and i had to reinstall all of my moduels including dpy.

The solution is to follow what it says

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Didn't solve the problem for me; I had done all this before getting to this answer, and continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem with a package with yarl, multidict dependencies. To fix it, I just upgraded my pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install discord
```

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE JAN 8, 2021: Discord.py v1.6 has been released, changelogs include a bump in the dependencies for building wheels

Old message below

If you want to stay on 3.9:

- Install Devon's personal builds of aiohttp, multidict, yarl, and PyNaCl (https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5984#issuecomment-727684359), e.g.:
  `py -3.9 -m pip install --upgrade discord.py[voice] --extra-index-url https://gorialis.github.io/pip/`
- Install the Micosoft Visual C++ standalone compilers (https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) and try to install discord.py in a Native Tools Command Prompt
- Install from the latest development version of discord.py on the master branch (https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#installing), e.g.:
  `py -3.9 -m pip install --upgrade "discord.py[voice] @ git+git://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git"`
- Install multidict and yarl from precompiled wheels on [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) (note, PyNaCl for voice support is not supplied there)
- Install the latest versions of discord.py's dependencies and install discord.py without dependencies, e.g.:
  `py -3.9 -m pip install --upgrade aiohttp pynacl`
  `py -3.9 -m pip install --upgrade discord.py --no-dependencies`
- Use Python 3.8, for which prebuilt wheels are available for the dependency versions discord.py v1.5.1 uses
- Wait for discord.py v1.6.0 to be released(RELEASED JAN 8 2021)

Up to date as of January 8, 2021

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem with `multidict` when I moved a different project to Python 3.12 (error bellow). The easiest solution I found was to avoid building it as documented in their repo's README.

```bash
$ MULTIDICT_NO_EXTENSIONS=1 pip install multidict
```

However, if you do rely on the library heavily and care about its performance, installing Visual C++ Build Tools is the way to go.

The error in my case for reference:

```bash
  ...
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Using latest versions of the libraries (instead of versions mentioned in repo) `yarl`, `multidict`, `pandas` for the [apache superset](https://superset.apache.org/) setup on Mac M2 Apple Chip fixes this problem.