# (Python: discord) ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python

I have had a problem with this all ready. I have tried many solutions however they haven't been able to do much. The first time round it said it needed to have c++ 14 or later so I downloaded that and now I have this message. I'm not sure as why is says that it failed to exit the code. If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
 C:\Users\Scott>pip install discord
 Collecting discord
 Using cached discord-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
 Collecting discord.py>=1.0.1
 Using cached discord.py-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (701 kB)
 Processing 
  c:\users\scott\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\9c\bd\6b99bc6ec9dab11f3756d31fb8506d3ecf07aea58b6201f539 
  \aiohttp-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
 Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in 
 c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0- 
 >discord.py>=1.0.1->discord) (3.0.4)
 Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
 Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
 Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in 
 c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0- 
 >discord.py>=1.0.1->discord) (20.3.0)
 Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
 Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
 Installing build dependencies ... done
 Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
 Preparing wheel metadata ... done
 Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
 Using cached yarl-1.5.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
 Installing build dependencies ... done
 Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
 Preparing wheel metadata ... done
 Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in 
 c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0- 
 >aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.0.1->discord) (2.10)
 Building wheels for collected packages: multidict, yarl
 Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 
 'c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site- 
 packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 
 'C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpie_k6tbo'
   cwd: C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-miy3epan\multidict
 Complete output (46 lines):
 **********************
 * Accellerated build *
 **********************
 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 running egg_info
 writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
 writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
 writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
 reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
 no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
 writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
 running build_ext
 building 'multidict._multidict' extension
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\multidict
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
 /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include - 
 Ic:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
 Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include /Tcmultidict/_multidict.c 
 /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\multidict/_multidict.obj -O2
 _  multidict.c
 c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: 
 Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit 
 code 2
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
 Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 
 'c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site- 
 packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 
 'C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplcm8zc1m'
   cwd: C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-miy3epan\yarl
  Complete output (41 lines):
 **********************
 * Accellerated build *
 **********************
 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 running egg_info
 writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
 writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
 writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
 writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
 reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
 no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
 writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
 running build_ext
 building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\yarl
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
 /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include - 
 Ic:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
 Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include /Tcyarl/_quoting_c.c 
 /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\yarl/_quoting_c.obj
 _quoting_c.c
 c:\users\scott\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: 
 Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit 
 code 2
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
 Failed to build multidict yarl
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python: discord.py) ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497319/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use)

Comment: No I have saw that one before but I have downloaded c++

Comment: You need a C compiler on your computer. I know on Linux you can install ```gcc``` but I don't know what you need to do on Windows.

Comment: What does that do