# Error while trying to install discord.py - "Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

Tags: python, pip, discord

I tryied to get discord.py and used `pip install discord.py` in my cmd and i got an error
then i got visual studio building tool and some other packages and it is still not working. Please help.

[Here is the error code](https://pastebin.com/unSKQWbr)

I looked at some other posts that stack overflow has and tried all methods but i still cant download discord.py

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python: discord.py) ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497319/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use)

Comment: i tried it but it didn't help

Comment: @RandomDavis - it seems they have a different error.  Your URL suggests a mismatched c++ version.  The root error here seems to be `'io.h': No such file or directory` - sounds like a missing dependency to me...or possibly a path configuration issue.

Comment: @YegorGuy did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @RandomDavis - good catch.  Hope that's the secret sauce.

Comment: @YegorGuy and it didn't work? How? Or did it? When did you try it? After I linked it or before you posted this question? I'm trying to help you troubleshoot

Comment: Whait i dont understant how to fix this problem