# ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl, multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pynacl

When I try to install PyNaCl, it shows me the error:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl, multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I'm trying to install it for a discord raid tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497319/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python: discord.py) ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497319/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use)

Comment: No they dont i installed that visual studio microsoft cpp tools v14.0 but i still get the error i need help