# Unable to install discord py with pip

Tags: python, installation, cmd, discord, discord.py

i have python 3.11 downloaded, and i installed pip with it.
however, i can't install discord py with

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

i've tried a few other ways, still didn't work.

in the end it says:

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

there are a few other errors throughout the process.

Comment: Can you post all the  log of errors? Might be able to help better!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, it seems it might be a problem due to dependencies to yarl and multidict (happens). I've had the same problem with itertools, and even opencv taking extremely long to build with a non-upgraded pip version!

Have you tried [upgrading pip](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl)? [Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497319/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use) with those libraries' dependencies.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

If pip direct installation doesn't work, try cloning the git repo:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pip install discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `pip install discord`